# Object pandas has no attribute name Series

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

```
import pandas as pd
numbers = {1,2,3,4,5}
ser = pd.Series(numbers)
print ser
```

I write this code in python for pandas series. but it's giving this

> "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Series'"

please help me

Comment: Do you have a python file called `pandas.py` by any chance?

Answer (score 26):

The Error in my problem is the file name.

I save the file as pandas.py that's why i got the error.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Please tell me what will be the file extension. I am getting this error in VS Code

Comment: you should not save you python file with name padas. that's my problem

Answer (score 3):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html

> data : array-like, dict, or scalar value Contains data stored in
>   Series

Don't think a set counts as array-like, so just convert it to a list before calling pd.Series.

```
import pandas as pd
numbers = {1,2,3,4,5}
ser = pd.Series(list(numbers))
```

Output:

```
print ser

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
```

Comment: Hii Liam, Mistake is I saved the file as pandas.py thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Import pandas as pd

a={1:"Ajith",2:"Kannan"} 
pd.Series(a)

Output:

1      Ajith

2      Kannan

Series is using capital S

Answer (score 0):

Actually any directory, file type with name pandas in the project will raise this error.

I had a pandas.ipynb notebook and a directory in the project, which was causing this issue. After renaming the file and the Directory it just worked fine.

thank you @Praveen.883 for bring attention toward the problem.

Answer (score -1):

change the file name from pandas.py to any other name